# Order query by row from another table (ruby rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have somewhat of a convoluted setup.

I am querying all users that have a thread (`Conversations`) of messages.

My User model has a `has_many` relation on two columns in `Conversation`

```
  has_many :sender_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: "sender_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recipient_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: "recipient_id", dependent: :destroy
```

I needed a way to get the latest conversation since any user can have multiple threads.

To achieve this, I have the following methods on the user model:

```
 def conversations
   sender_conversations.or(recipient_conversations)
  end

  def latest_conversation
    conversations.order(updated_at: :desc).first
  end
```

Conversation model:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  ...

  validates :sender_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:recipient_id, :property_id] }

  scope :between, ->(sender_id, recipient_id) do
    where(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id).or(
      where(sender_id: recipient_id, recipient_id: sender_id)
    )
  end
...
```

The controller action is querying users that have either a `sender_id` or `recipient_id`

```
def users_with_existing_conversations
    authorize! :users_with_existing_conversations, Conversation

    @users = User.accessible_by(current_ability, :index_conversations)

    @users = @users.where(id: Conversation.select(:sender_id))
                    .or(@users.where(id: Conversation.select(:recipient_id)))


    ...




  end
```

Then finally, in the view, I'm looping through

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr class="table__row" onclick="window.location.href = '/conversations?user_id=<%= user.id %>'">
    <td><%= user.name %>(<%= user.id %>)</td>
    <td><%= user.surname %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.company_name.present? ? user.company_name : "N/A" %></td>
    <td><%= user.role.capitalize %></td>
    <td><%= user.created_at.try(:strftime, '%b %d, %Y') %></td>
    <td><%= user.latest_conversation.updated_at.localtime.strftime('%b %d, %Y at %l:%M %p') %></td>
    <td class="table__more">
      <%= link_to "Show details", conversations_path(user_id: user.id), class: 'table__row__details button button--tertiary button--tertiary-small' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Now what I can't figure out is how to order these rows by the `latest_conversation` which is the `updated_at` column.

So I have a users table I'm querying, but I want to order the query by their relation with the conversations table's `updated_at` column.

Comment: You can't because you're not using the `conversations` table at any moment. Try with `User.joins(:sender_conversations, :recipient_conversations).order('conversations.created_at')`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma joining causes the query to return no results. really lost on this one. essentially, i just need to query all users that have a conversation thread going, whether they're the sender or receiver

Comment: Yes, you're right. Try a theta join using the `IN` clause `User.joins('INNER JOIN conversations ON users.id IN (conversations.sender_id, conversations.recipient_id)').order('conversations.created_at')`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma you save me again. that worked. I don't know if I mentioned, but I'm tasked with finishing an already started rails project after having zero experience with ruby and ruby on rails. and their design choices are horrible. do you want to put an answer so I can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a custom `INNER JOIN` using the `IN` clause to check both `conversations`' columns:

```
User.joins('INNER JOIN conversations c ON users.id IN (c.sender_id, c.recipient_id)')
    .order('c.created_at')
```

Comment: many thanks, sir. I did notice that if I change the order to use "asc" instead, the results are a bit funky. For instance, I'm getting an order on a few rows like `nov 17,2019 1:11PM`,  `nov 17,2019 11:01AM`, `nov 17,2019 1:11PM`

Comment: You're welcome ;). Is that wrong? Are these values from the users or conversations rows?

Comment: when the order is `.order('conversations.updated_at desc')` , it's correct. but when changed to `.order('conversations.updated_at asc')`, the 11:01AM should come before the 1:11PM rows. not sure why it's doing that. and this is from the conversations table. the `updated_at` column.

Comment: That's because you're accessing the conversations from each user. Every pair of conversations (recipient, sender) are sorted by the order you specify with `order`. If you need to access the conversations columns, you should start from that table and then include users.

Comment: I did think that made more sense, but I wasn't sure how. If there are 4 rows in the conversations table, there still may be 6 users i'd have to grab since it's focused on the sender and receiver foreign key columns. I'll keep what I have no and get rid of the time. hehe. thanks again